# how to import a theme in liferay 7 workspace?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7, liferay-theme

how to import a theme in liferay 7 workspace?

I added the theme under workspace/themes and I tried to deploy it but did not work. The build type of my Theme is Ant.

The following picture shows the details:

[image]

I put the Theme under ***sdk\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.11\themes*** and I tried to test it as in Liferay 6. **Import-> Liferay Projects from plugins SDK** then when adding the SDK I got an error :

> app.server.dir is invalid. Please reconfigure Plugins SDK setting:
>   app.server.dir=path to liferay portal/tomcat-8.0.32

Then I tried to migrate the theme from the plugins sdk liferay workspace.
I puted the sdk under: `liferay-workspace\plugins-sdk\sdk\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.11`

Then I tried this commande `C:\Users\User1\workspace2\liferay-workspace>blade convert --themebuilder name_theme` she does not return anything.

The structure of the original theme:

[image]

The css directory:

[image]

I fixed the problem ***app.server.dir is invalid.*** by switching the java jdk from 8 to 7 in eclipse.ini file:

```
-vm
D:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.79/bin/javaw.exe
```

When I did **Import-> Liferay Projects from plugins SDK** and I puted the SDK path, I got this error:

> No available projects can be imported.

Do I need to upgrade it?

#### Update:

Sorry, I checked the compatibility of Theme. The theme is already compatible with Liferay 7 and no need to upgrade it.

```
<look-and-feel>
    <compatibility>
        <version>7.0.2+</version>
    </compatibility>
    ...
</look-and-feel>
```

I am trying to import the Theme on ***Liferay 7.0.0 GA1***.

1-  I am using jdk 1.8 for eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3).

Image description:

[image]

2-  I updated sdk /build.{ username}.properties

Image description:

[image]

3- I putted the Theme under `sdk\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\themes` and I did ***Import-> Liferay Projects from plugins SDK*** and I putted the SDK path `D:\FormationJEE\Liferay\Liferay7_g1\sdk\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0`. I do not find the theme. I did Refresh and it does not appear.

Image description:

[image]

I followed @OlafKock 's instructions:

I declared the compatibility with 7.0.0+ and when I did **Import-> Liferay Projects from plugins SDK** I did not have the right to put the path of sdk. It is set by default to this: *D:\FormationJEE\Liferay\Liferay7_g1\sdk\liferay-plugins-sdk-‌​7.0*. I do not find the theme. I did Refresh and it does not appear.

Now, I can not change the path of sdk anymore. It is stuck at *D:\FormationJEE\Liferay\Liferay7_g1\sdk\liferay-plugins-sdk-‌​‌​7.0*. I can not test the theme on Liferay 7.0 GA5.

I fixed that by creating another workspace but still can not import the theme project.

4- Hello, I tried to migrate the theme from the plugins sdk to workspace using this command:

> blade convert --themebuilder [THEME_PROJECT_NAME]

I typed the command and nothing happens.
I followed this link:
[MIGRATING A THEME FROM THE PLUGINS SDK TO WORKSPACE](https://dev.liferay.com/fr/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/migrating-a-theme-from-the-plugins-sdk-to-workspace)

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade existing liferay 6 theme refer following url

```
https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/upgrading-themes
```

use following command to upgrade your existing liferay 6 theme.

```
gulp upgrade
```

You can build liferay 7 theme using following url, and copy your existing liferay theme css, js and portal files to new theme directory.

```
https://web.liferay.com/web/smgulnaaz/blog/-/blogs/theme-creation-in-liferay-7
```

Comment: I got an error: Local gulp not found in liferay-workspace\plugins-sdk\sdk\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.11\myTheme

Comment: Install Node.js (v4.2.2), npm and then from command prompt install gulp using following "npm install gulp - g"

Comment: refer - https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/themes-generator

Comment: pls I need more help. I already have Node.js installed and npm. I taped the command in Node.js command prompt and I got an error. where should I write the commande?

Comment: Use "npm install -g gulp" to install local gulp tool. You can type it from your workflow/themes directory. Send me your theme src. Let me know.

Comment: I typed `C:\Users\User1\workspace2\liferay-workspace\themes>npm install -g gulp`. there are warnings, but I think it works. Now, where to type `gulp upgrade` commande?

Comment: In your theme’s root directory modules\inspinia7, run "gulp upgrade". It will upgrade existing liferay 6.2 theme to liferay 7.

Comment: pls a lite help I am confused. I already have my theme under `liferay-workspace/themes` and when I typed `npm install -g gulp` it was changed. how to do it properly?

Comment: if its already upgraded, try running gulp deploy, if it generate war, your theme is upgraded to workspace if not then attached your theme code.

Comment: I can't give you the code. I tried **gulp upgrade** and **gulp deploy** `C:\Users\User1\workspace2\liferay-workspace\themes\inspinia7>gulp upgrade
[17:54:09] No gulpfile found`

Comment: create new theme under liferay-workspace/themes/ and manually copy css js and template files

Comment: the theme has been modified. from 28 mo to 7 mo? and I do not understand what I'm doing?

Comment: see the update. pls I need to know if you've done that before. and is it possible to repeat the steps properly? stay with me.

Comment: recently i've upgrade liferay 6 theme to liferay 7. please expand css directory? Also let me know if you using vm template or ftl file.

Comment: pls see the update. I don't think there is a vm template or a ftl file.

Comment: I really need a help.

Comment: vm or freemaker files are in templates directory. Ok you can do one thing, create new theme following instruction from this link https://web.liferay.com/web/smgulnaaz/blog/-/blogs/theme-creation-in-liferay-7. Once you create theme, copy your existing css/js/templates/fonts from your existing theme/_diff folder to new workspace theme/directory. It would be much easier.

Comment: can I test the theme as in Liferay 6. **Import-> Liferay Projects from plugins SDK** I got an error:  **app.server.dir is invalid. Please reconfigure Plugins SDK setting: app.server.dir=path to liferay portal/tomcat-8.0.32** when adding the SDK.

Comment: you could check this one "app.server.tomcat.dir=${app.server.parent.dir}/tomcat-*** " in build.properties file of plugin sdk, if it is different with your tomcat version, you could config "app.server.tomcat.dir" in your build.${username}.properties file or change tomcat version in build.properties file.

Comment: The "app.server.tomcat.dir" is the same as the tomcat version. I created a  build.username.properties file and I added **app.server.type** , **app.server.parent.dir** , **app.server.tomcat.dir** still the same problem.

Comment: you mean `app.server.parent.dir= D:\\FormationJEE\\Liferay\\Liferay7_ga4\\tomcat\\liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga4`

Comment: I followed the blog and I created a Theme and I copied the files css / js / templates / fonts from my existing **theme/_diff** folder to **liferay-7-theme/src**. Now, what do I have to do?

Comment: great do that gulp build and gulp deploy on your new created theme root folder.

Comment: ok, done , there some warnings: `[23:17:40] D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/util.rb:1074: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated`

Comment: you can resolve warning. try deploy and test on liferay server if everything works fine

Comment: I am using Liferay 7.0.3 GA4. I am in **Control Panel -> site Templates** there is no theme, there is only "Community Site" and "Intranet Site" How to deploy it on the Liferay server?

Comment: it should be in look and feel not site templates.

Comment: where do I find it?

Comment: site - navigation - configure

Comment: It works. this is the new theme that I created and for the other one?

Comment: Now, what do I have to do?

Comment: Sorry, I checked the compatibility of Theme. The theme is already compatible with Liferay 7 and no need to upgrade it. I putted the Theme under /themes  and I did Import-> Liferay Projects from plugins SDK and I putted the SDK path. I do not find the theme. I did Refresh and it does not appear. please check the Update3.

Comment: Hello, I tried to migrate the theme from the plugins sdk to workspace using this command "blade convert --themebuilder nameThemeProject". I typed the command and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but: Try 7.0 GA5. It might have fixed an issue that you're running into. Also, it might help the mismatch of your stated version and the declared compatibility

```
<look-and-feel>
    <compatibility>
        <version>7.0.2+</version>
    </compatibility>
    ...
</look-and-feel>
```

7.0.2+ refers to "7.0 GA3 and later", but you state that you're using GA1.
Many issues have been fixed since then. Do a quick try declaring compatibility with 7.0.0+, but, by all means, use the most current version as a long term fix.

Comment: I declared the compatibility with 7.0.0+  and when I did **Import-> Liferay Projects from plugins SDK** I did not have the right to put the path of sdk. It is set by default to this: **D:\FormationJEE\Liferay\Liferay7_g1\sdk\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0**. I do not find the theme. I did Refresh and it does not appear.

Comment: Now, I can not change the path of sdk anymore.
It is stuck at **D:\FormationJEE\Liferay\Liferay7_g1\sdk\liferay-plugins-sdk-‌​7.0**. I can not test the theme on Liferay 7.0 GA5.

Comment: I fixed that by creating another workspace but still can not import the theme project.