# Why i cannot found the theme project in the import window in Liferay 7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-theme, liferay-ide

I posted this question the other day [how to import a theme in liferay 7 workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181091/how-to-import-a-theme-in-liferay-7-workspace) but wasn't able to get a good answer, so now I'm asking again.

I am using Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) and Liferay Portal 7.0.0 GA1.
I downloaded the sdk, the src and the Tomcat from here 
[Liferay Portal / 7.0.0 GA1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/7.0.0%20GA1/).

I tried to import the Theme with Eclipse.

The theme is compatible with Liferay 7 and ***the build type of the Theme is Ant***:

```
<look-and-feel>
    <compatibility>
        <version>7.0.2+</version>
    </compatibility>
    ...
</look-and-feel>
```

- I am using jdk 1.8 for eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3):

  -vm
  D:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javaw.exe
- I updated sdk /build.{ username}.properties:

  app.server.type=tomcat
  app.server.parent.dir=D:\FormationJEE\Liferay\Liferay7_g1\tomcat\liferay-portal-7.0-ce-ga1
  app.server.tomcat.dir=${app.server.parent.dir}/tomcat-8.0.32
- I putted the Theme under `sdk\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\themes` and I did ***Import-> Liferay Projects from plugins SDK*** and I putted the SDK path `D:\FormationJEE\Liferay\Liferay7_g1\sdk\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0`. I do not find the theme. I did Refresh and it does not appear.

**It is a serious problem** I downloaded the project from the gitlab and I could not import it. Is there is access right that's blocking me?

Comment: instead of asking yet another question, please edit the existing one - often no-answer is a sign for the question not being understood well enough.

Comment: @OlafKock yes, I updated the old question. It is now on the Update3. there is no good answer.

Comment: @OlafKock pls I need some help.

Comment: @OlafKock *It is a serious problem* I downloaded the project from the gitlab and I could not import it. Is there is access right that's blocking me?

Comment: I'm not often working on the theme side, thus I'm rather quiet in this regard. You might want to try again with a current release (7.0 GA5 is current) to see if you run into an issue that's fixed. Edit: This triggered something that I've answered in the original question.

Comment: @OlafKock The story started from here a user tried a trial version of theme on Liferay 7.0.3 GA4 and he had an error. I  tried to test the Theme on Liferay 7.0.3 GA4 to reproduce the error but I failed to imported. I am new on liferay. I was told to test the theme on Liferay7 GA1 version. and it's my second week trying to import it. I'll tried with Liferay 7.0 GA5.